# Latest Clang location in XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, clang, xcode4.5

I've updated XCode to 4.5 (with iOS 6) and installed latest command line tools.
Before that i always had the latest Clang version in

```
/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
```

(clang and clang++ binaries), but now, with the last update, they are gone and i only have gcc and llvm stuff. I've checked 'clang' bins all over my Mac and found one in

```
/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XCodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

But why so? First, why i have no clang in previous folder, where it always was, and second, it is the valid way to use as 'default location for clang' this xctoolchain folder (e.g., for cmake in project repository)

**EDIT**: for Xcode 5 and more, clang is again present in .xctoolchain folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed the "command line tools for Xcode" you would have clang in a nice, intuitive location like "`/usr/bin`".

To get at them, you can go in via Xcode's preferences like this:

[image: install command line components via Xcode]

or you can click the "Looking for additional developer tools" link at http://developer.apple.com/xcode, where there's a disk image and an installer you can download.

Both of these options install the exact same components.

Comment: Thanks for response, but i've already installed them (as i told in question ;) ) And don't have clang in there since XCode 4.5

Comment: If you've already installed the command line tools, don't you see clang in "`/usr/bin`" already?

Comment: i have it in 'second' `/usr/bin` which is located in /Toolchains folder, not in the first.

Comment: that's just not the answer mate...;/

Comment: Sorry it's not the answer you were looking for. I'm not sure why you don't see clang in your "`/usr/bin`" directory after installing the command line tools, but now that I'm looking at your original question again, I'm not even certain what your question ***was***?  Nobody should be doing command line or shell script stuff with tools that are buried deep within the Xcode application package (which is likely to be changed or modified or moved or whatever).  Tools installed properly and for use from the command line are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for response! I have it in my `/usr/bin` folder in the very root of the hard drive, but i actually want the location somewhere in XCode folder..

Comment: @dreamzor: See my question for Clang new location inside the Xcode folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354029/with-xcode-4-5-2-clang-compiler-seems-not-to-be-sdk-version-dependent-why?lq=1

Comment: Well it least that helped me.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann One excellent reason to use toolchains buried deep within the Xcode appliation package is to cross-compile libraries that expect the (very standard) "configure ; make clean ; make" workflow.

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti's question just redirects back here! But I found some relevant info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636315/how-to-compile-libcurl-with-arch-armv7s-under-macosx