# how to compile libcurl with arch armv7s under macosx?

Tags: macos, libcurl, cross-compiling

I have installed Xcode 4.5 and iOS6.0 SDK , MacOSX 10.7 SDK,command line tools on my computer. I download libcurl from http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.27.0.tar.gz and compiled it for iOS with arch armv7s.

I did follows:

1. > `export
   >   CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
   >   -arch armv7s"`
   >
   > export LDFLAG="-isysroot
   >   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
   >   --Wl,-syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk"
   >
   > export CFLAG="-isysroot
   >   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk"
2. > ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin10

and get errors below:

```
    $ ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin10
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for arm-apple-darwin10-ar... no
checking for ar... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin10-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking curl version... 7.27.0
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin10
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-apple-darwin10-gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/Users/eric/working/curl-7.27.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

does anyone known how to do it?

Comment: I resolved this problem.
1) remove the "-arch armv7s" arguments from CC and added it to CFLAGS.
2) configure --host arguments set to "armv7s-apple-darwin10"

and now it can be compiled success.

Comment: Pro-tip: you can use the `xcrun` tool to easily refer to the proper version of clang (i.e. the one from the iOS toolchain): `CC=$(shell xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find clang)`