# With Xcode 4.5.2, Clang compiler seems not to be SDK version dependent. Why?

Tags: clang, xcode4.5

With Xcode 4.4 and earlier versions, each SDK used to have either a copy or a symlink to a Clang compiler available at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
    SDKs/iPhoneOS${IPHONE_SDKVERSION}.sdk/usr/bin/clang++
```

With Xcode 4.5.2, there is no Clang compiler at the path above. However, I found it at

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
```

**b) Why does it not depend on the SDK version anymore ?**

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525247/latest-clang-location-in-xcode-4-5?rq=1

Comment: That question just links back here!

Answer (score 2):

It's because clang can compile for multiple architectures with a single (top-level) binary.  The previous gcc-based toolchains needed one gcc per arch.

See [how to compile libcurl with arch armv7s under macosx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636315/how-to-compile-libcurl-with-arch-armv7s-under-macosx) for examples of passing arch flags to clang.

Also, you can use xcrun to find your tools instead of hardcoding their locations.  For example, when cross compiling for iOS:

```
export CC=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang`
```