# How to install the Python development headers on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, header, homebrew

For a project using Boost.Python (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929566/need-help-getting-started-with-boost-python)) I need the Python development headers containing e.g. `pyconfig.h`.

These are apparently missing from my system. I've installed Python 3 via Homebrew:

```
cls ~ $ brew info python3
python3: stable 3.3.0
http://www.python.org/
Depends on: pkg-config, readline, sqlite, gdbm
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.3 (4420 files, 78M)
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0 (4843 files, 93M) *
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/python3.rb
```

I would prefer getting the headers via Homebrew, too, but I cannot find a package for them.

```
cls ~ $ brew search python-dev
No formula found for "python-dev". Searching open pull requests...
```

What are my options for installing these headers? Is there a Homebrew package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are these the headers you are looking for:

```
Cellar/python3/3.3.0//Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m/
```

Comment: Probably yes, they include the missing `pyconfig.h`. I'll try to tell this to my gcc as an include path.

Comment: Is there any reason why they are not linked to /usr/local/include/python3.3? They are hard to find and as soon as a new version of python is released (eg 3.3.1) the paths stops working..

Answer (score 35):

The latest Python 3 formula links a program called `python3-config`. You can use it to find the headers like this:

`python3-config --include`

On my machine, this outputs:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m
```

You may need to `brew update && brew rm python3 && brew install python3` to enable this.

There is an equivalent program called `python-config` for Python 2.

Comment: Along these lines, it appears that the latest ``brew install smpeg --HEAD smpeg`` looks for this python-config, but in text context of a virutalenv the build system couldn't find it.  I symlinked the correct python3-config to my virtualenv's ``bin/python-config``, and things got better.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if that's a bug. Perhaps you could open an issue [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues?state=open).

Comment: If you are in any virtual env, python3-config should give you the desired result. You can verify the path using which python3-config