# Issue installing Numpy on Mac OSX using virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I am attempting to install Numpy via pip (Python version 2.7.5) and keep running into an error that states:

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel

I am using virtualenv with virtualenv wrapper if that helps. I installed python via homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python development package from homebrew:

```
brew install python-dev
```

### edit

Indeed, the homebrew formula does not exist. You could find the missing headers by following these steps:
[How to install the Python development headers on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931331/how-to-install-the-python-development-headers-on-mac-os-x) but I am not sure where should should link them to.

Comment: It states that there is "No available formula for python-dev"

Comment: The provided link says to include the directory as a GCC include path. Looking in to how to do that.

Comment: The header file I am looking for (Python.h) does not exist in the directory specified by the provided link