# Installing Mathics under Mac Os X

Tags: python, macos, mathics

I am trying to install [Mathics](http://www.mathics.org) under Mac Os X Mavericks. The installation instructions states to install 3 libraries in advance (besides python): `python-dev`, `libsqlite3-dev`, and `libgmp3-dev`. I used Homebrew to install python but I can't find the other libraries. I found an [article here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931331/how-to-install-the-python-development-headers-on-mac-os-x) on how to find the headers but I do not know what to do to continue the installation. Running `python initialize.py` as stated in the instructions I get an error

`/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'initialize.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

So, what are the replacements for the libraries in Homebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the current Mathics maintainer.

Sorry, the instructions on the website are out of date. Instead, try

```
python setup.py initialize
```

The instructions on the [wiki](https://github.com/poeschko/Mathics/wiki/Installing) are up to date. (I haven't got access to the Mathics website so I can't fix them there).

Apologies again for the outdated documentation.

Comment: Thanks! May I also note that a Django version of >1.5 seems also to make the installation fail.