# How do I install `libgmp3-dev` on OSX?

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

I encountered an error when I installed the `1.8.3` version of the `json` gem:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_str_new_static 
  Referenced from: /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-   1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle 
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

It was recommended on the [json issue thread](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/259) that `libgmp3-dev` be installed.

There are instructions for installing it on Linux but I've been unable to find any instructions for installing it on OSX.

Comment: Did you try google, because it was the first result.

Comment: @Ekult3k Did you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493260/installing-mathics-under-mac-os-x ? The only answer there provides instructions for installing a math library for Python.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev

Comment: Then install the gem

Comment: @Ekult3k Seriously???  The question title says OSX...  apt-get is only available for Debian based Linux distros...

Comment: @Ekult3k - `apt-get` is an Ubuntu command. It does not work on OSX (at least not for me...)

Comment: Same issue on windows... how to resolve it there?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue resolved itself after a reboot. There was no need to install `libgmp3-dev` as this was already installed by xcode.

I discovered that the issue was not caused by the `json` module but by `rvm` when it discovers a `ruby` binary.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 2):

To install libgmp3-dev on mac:

`brew install gmp`