# Installing psycopg2 fails completely. Huge error message (such as error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1)

Tags: python, macos, pip, psycopg2

I have a problem with installing `psycopg2` on my mac. I tried several things such as installing it with `pip` and also homebrew. I also downloaded all dependencies but it still fails to install it.

I get the following error message, which looks horrifying:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/1c/nhs40gy513143dfqyblmt3r80000gn/T/pip-install-rxlPem/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/1c/nhs40gy513143dfqyblmt3r80000gn/T/pip-record-93LksX/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1c/nhs40gy513143dfqyblmt3r80000gn/T/pip-install-rxlPem/psycopg2/
```

What could be the issue?

**EDIT:** Full error can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/yL3BzJeG), and this appears to be the most relevant part:

```
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:34:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h:25:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You are cython installed in your system? If not try to install it.

Comment: @TiagoHenriqueBarbosaAlves, what does Cython have to do with anything?

Comment: Al, are you using Anaconda? Do you have a virtualenv? You can also try installing [`psycopg2-binary`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) instead of `psycopg2`.

Comment: @Chris psycopg2 is a python library builded in C. So you need then to compile the source code before install psycopg2.

Comment: Cython not installed and not really relevant for my issue?

Comment: @TiagoHenriqueBarbosaAlves, it's true that `psycopg2` is written in C. But that still has nothing to do with Cython. You don't need Cython to build Python libraries written in C.

Comment: @Chris no, I do not have a virtualenv (I am still a beginner). psychopg2-binary installed without any issues.

Answer (score 4):

`psycopg2` [has some install dependencies that might be giving you trouble](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source). In this case it looks like the install process can't find [`stdio.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output), part of the C standard library. [Installing the Xcode Command Line Tools](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/) might help.

But if you don't want to bother with this, try installing [`psycopg2-binary`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) instead:

> You can also obtain a stand-alone package, not requiring a compiler or external libraries, by installing the [psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) package from PyPI:
>
> ```
> $ pip install psycopg2-binary
> ```
>
> The binary package is a practical choice for development and testing but in production it is advised to use the package built from sources.

Comment: I tried to check the dependencies and I have fulfilled pretty much everything on the list:


Python version 2.7 Check! (Pre-Installed on Mac)
Python 3 versions from 3.4 to 3.7 Check! (Installed)
PostgreSQL server versions from 7.4 to 11 Check! (updated)
PostgreSQL client library version from 9.1 Check! (installed)

Comment: You'll also need Python headers for whichever version you're using (and you [might need to explicitly provide their location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931544/354577) and PostgreSQL headers (maybe `libpq`?). But if you were able to install `psycopg2-binary` why do you still want to install `psycopg2`?

Comment: If you really want to go down that rabbit hole check out [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33866695/354577). But unless you have a specific need to build `psycopg2` from source you might as well just stick with `psycopg2-binary`. It's a much simpler solution for a development box.

Comment: I have tried that solution, also did not work... I posted the FULL error (it is huge) under this link: https://pastebin.com/yL3BzJeG Maybe this helps?

Comment: I'm still curious why `psycopg2-binary` doesn't meet your needs. Is there a specific reason you must build `psycopg2` from source? In any case, I've updated my answer based on the extended output you provided.

Comment: To be completely honest, I do not know how to use psycopg2-binary, because import psycopg2 is not working and I do not find any documentation about using binary

Comment: @AlNikolaj, it's exactly the same thing except it's not built from source. Use `import psycopg2` and away you go.

Comment: ok, then I have the next issue haha I have sycopg2-binary installed, but when I try to import the package, it says "ImportError: No module named psycopg2"

Comment: That sounds like a general issue with the way you're installing packages. IMO that's a separate issue. Are you using a virtual environment? Are you installing with `pip`? Poetry? Pipenv? `conda`? Homebrew?

Comment: I usually use pip, but due to this issue I installed Homebrew since it was recommended. I might just re-install the whole entire OS...

Answer (score 2):

for anybody looking for solution or future reference to this,

I faced this issue while installing psycopg2 on Mojave, following on, i could find link to psycopg2 github  [issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/903). which has the solution as installing missing library header, using

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

This is probably an issue with Mojave, [enter link description here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249)

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this issue with a Debian distribution can use this solution

Install the development headers for postgresql:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
```

then try:

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

hope this solves your issues